# Git fetch fails with couldn't read password error

Tags: git, jenkins, build, passwords, config

```
Team, we are trying to do git fetch origin. Its is failing with incorrect device or password. We are using the correct password in the git clone url. Please check below and help to resolve the error.

+ /opt/app/git/2.9.0-05/bin/git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /opt/app/test_node/sdt-devops.vci.xxx.com_1234/sharedspace/.git/
+ /opt/app/git/2.9.0-05/bin/git config --list --show-origin
file:.git/config       core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config       core.filemode=true
file:.git/config       core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config       core.bare=false
file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=https://test@codecloud.web.test.com/scm/st_xxx/test.git
+ /opt/app/git/2.9.0-05/bin/git fetch --all
Fetching origin
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://test@codecloud.web.test.com': No such device or address
error: Could not fetch origin
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Above the logs for the code where we used these git init and git fetch --all commands from Jenkins execute shell.We tried using ssh in place of https that also no success.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any proxy setup for the jenkins. I guess the server dns is not getting resolved. Can you check the dns and the access to the server ?